# How to load an external css file before the compressed css?

Tags: meteor

I need to load a external css file but need to load it before the compressed css files so I can override it's styles with my own. How can I do it?

The main reason to make this css file (semantic-ui) external is to reduce the build time. What if I move it to a package? Will meteor compress the css file every-time it reloads?

Comment: If you want to override styles in css you need to load _after_ the styles you wish to override. If you name this file `zCss` (for example) you can force it to load later.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Actually I need to override `zCss` file with my custome css files :-)

Comment: Then you want them to load *last*. There is no zCss except if you name your file that.

Comment: The problem is, when i add an external css file (the zCss file according to our example), it will load last. My custom css files in the meteor app load first. I need the external file to load first.

Comment: Then follow your own suggestion and move it to a package. It will get compressed once and then should load quickly after that.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I just tried it but no improvement in the build time. :-( Looks like it's re-building the package every-time I make a change to a file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @THpubs This is correct behaviour for Meteor. It rebuilds whole package if you changed something.

Comment: @Tdm Ah ok thanks! Is there a way to use cache in the package? Or reduce the build time in any way?

Comment: If such feature exits I don't know about it. probably, it don't. Anyway this topic for discussion on meter forums.